# Is there a way to keep track of dates on Firestore using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I am building a NextJS app with Firebase as the back end. I am using Firestore.

I have a collection called purchases where any purchase that a user makes is recorded. The data looks like so:

```
{
  id: "", 
  date: timestamp,
  amount: 0,
  transactionCode: "",
  items: [],
  promo: false
}
```

I would like to have a function that sets the promo to true when it has been 72 hours or any specified time since the purchase was made.

I am stuck at creating a trigger that runs the updater function.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that scans your database for documents to update every minute or every five minutes. This is a good approach for popular applications with a consistent usage rate.

To improve efficiency, you can use a [Firestore onCreate trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) to defer a [Cloud Task Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions) to update the document. As each purchase is made, a Cloud Task can be scheduled to execute in 72 hours from the purchase date where it sets `promo` to `true`. This has the benefit of not running jobs that don't have any documents to update.

However, this is still wasteful as the frequency of purchases increases. Instead of actioning the document in exactly 72 hours for each one, we can schedule the tasks to cover five minute blocks. This would mean if some purchases were made at 00:02, 00:03, 00:03, and 00:04, only one cloud task will be scheduled to run at 00:00 three days from now that updates all 4 documents instead of 4 separate runs.

To start with, we need to get some boilerplate out of the way. The below block initializes the Firebase Admin SDK and defines some utility functions. The functions are used to prevent creating a Cloud Task for the same ID more than once and also to update as many documents as possible without throwing an error.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase-admin/functions";

const MILLIS_IN_72H = 259200000;
const MILLIS_IN_5M = 300000;

// Alternatively,
// const HOURS_UNTIL_PROMO_ACTIVATES = 72;
// const MILLIS_UNTIL_PROMO_ACTIVATES = HOURS_UNTIL_PROMO_ACTIVATES * 3600000; // 1h in ms

// you could lazy load the Firebase Admin SDK as needed
initializeApp();

// Attempts to create a "lock file" using a document to
// prevent multiple instances actioning the same task.
// Returns true if the lock was successfully claimed.
async function claimDocumentLock(docRef, docData) {
  return docRef.firestore.runTransaction(
    async (transaction) => {
      const docSnap = await transaction.get(docRef);
      
      if (docSnap.exists) {
        return false; // lock already claimed
      }
        
      transaction.create(docRef, docData);
      return true; // lock was successfully claimed
    }
  );
}

function getQueueTaskLockDocRef(queueName, id) {
  return getFirestore()
    .collection("tasks-" + queueName)
    .doc(id);
}

// Attempts to queue a task in the given queue, but gives up if
// a task with the given ID has already been queued. Returns true
// if the task was queued, false otherwise.
async function enqueueTaskOnce({ queueName, id, data, options }) {
  const taskLockDocRef = getQueueTaskLockDocRef(queueName, id);
  
  const lockClaimed = await claimDocumentLock(taskLockDocRef, data);

  if (!lockClaimed) {
    return false; // already exists
  }

  // "_lockPath" is stashed so the Cloud Task can remove it later
  const enqueueError = await getFunctions()
    .taskQueue(queueName)
    .enqueue({ ...data, _lockPath: taskLockDocRef.path }, options)
    .then(() => null, (err) => err);

  if (enqueueError) {
    // failed to queue? release the lock
    await taskLockDocRef.delete();

    // rethrow error
    throw enqueueError;
  }

  return true; // task queued successfully
}

// Creates update requests for each document in the given array
// and traps their errors so as many can succeed as possible
async function updateAsManyDocsAsPossible(docRefArray, data) {
  const updateResults = await Promise.all(docRefArray
    .map((docSnap) => (
      docSnap.ref
        .update({ ...data })
        .then(
          () => false, // use false for "completed with no error"
          (err) => `#${docSnap.id} (${err.code || "unknown"})`
        )
    ));

  return updateResults.filter(Boolean); // returns only failed update results
}
```

Next we need to wire up the Firestore Cloud Function that queues up Cloud Tasks for each incoming purchase. While executing this function, we also make sure that there isn't a Cloud Task already scheduled that would handle this purchase.

```
exports.schedulePromoPricingOnPurchase = functions.firestore
    .document('purchases/{purchaseId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const { eventId } = context,
        purchaseDateMS = snap.get("date").toMillis(), // assuming it's a Firestore Timestamp
        purchaseId = snap.id,
        queueName = "deferredUpdatePromoPricingStatus";
      
      // Calculates a unix timestamp for approx. 72h from now, rounded to the previous 5m interval
      // (e.g. 2023-01-01T00:00Z -> 2023-01-04T00:00Z, 2023-01-01T00:04Z -> 2023-01-01T00:00Z, 2023-01-01T00:05Z -> 2023-01-01T00:05Z)
      const scheduleTimeMS = purchaseDateMS + MILLIS_IN_72H - (purchaseDateMS % MILLIS_IN_5M);

      const wasQueued = await enqueueOnce({
        queueName,
        id: scheduleTimeMS,
        data: {
          eventId,
          purchaseId,
          timestamp: scheduleTimeMS
        },
        options: {
          scheduleTime: new Date(scheduleTimeMS),
          // dispatchDeadlineSeconds: 60 * 5 // 5 minutes
        }
      });

      if (wasQueued) {
        console.log(`New task scheduled for t:${scheduleTimeMS}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Task already scheduled for t:${scheduleTimeMS}`);
      }
    });
```

Next we define the Cloud Function that is executed by Cloud Tasks when a job is dispatched. The timestamp in our Firestore query can be extracted from the data we registered with Cloud Tasks when we queued it.

```
exports.deferredUpdatePromoPricingStatus = functions
    .tasks.taskQueue({
      retryConfig: {
        maxAttempts: 5,
        minBackoffSeconds: 60,
      },
      rateLimits: {
        maxConcurrentDispatches: 2,
      },
    }).onDispatch(async (data) => {
      const { timestamp, _lockPath } = data,
        db = getFirestore(),
        taskLockDocRef = _lockPath ? db.doc(_lockPath) : null;

      // Note: This query may require a compound query to be configured for promo and date.
      await qsPurchasesToUpdate = db
        .collection("purchases")
        .where("promo", "==", false)
        .where("date", ">=", timestamp) // this startAt point could be moved further into the past if desired
        .where("date", "<", timestamp + MILLIS_IN_5M)
        .get();

      // attempt to update each found document with promo=true
      const failedUpdates = await updateAsManyDocsAsPossible(qsPurchasesToUpdate.docs, { promo: true });

      if (failedUpdates.length) {
        console.error("One or more documents failed to be updated. Including: " + failedUpdates.join(","));
        // throwing an error will cause the document updates to be retried
        throw new Error("One or more documents failed to be updated.");
      }

      console.log(`Applied "promo=true" to ${querySnapshot.size} document(s).`); 

      // release lock if known
      if (taskLockDocRef) {
        await taskLockDocRef.delete()
          .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to release task lock for "${taskLockDocRef.path}"`, err));
      }
    });
```

**Note:** To deploy the above Cloud Task function, you may need to deploy it on its own first so it can [create the queue with the configured options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions#deploying_the_task_queue_function):

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:deferredUpdatePromoPricingStatus
```

**Note:** Once a Cloud Task is scheduled, it cannot be cancelled or removed by the Admin SDK. In the above function, even if all the purchases in that 5 minute block were deleted at some later time, the function would run, get no results to its query and then terminate safely.